Is it possible to install/use K8s safely in a personal laptop?
I am new in K8s and I was listening to a presentation where the person said that his preferred driver is Virtual Box because it is less probable to mess up your laptop if something goes wrong.
I was also checking the without driver option in the documentation and it seems that unless I really spend time to set things up I could essentially completely compromise my laptop.
So my question is: is K8s not meant to be used in a personal laptop as too risky especially if you are not familiar with Virtual Box/KVM or security implications if opting for no driver?
